# Why do ELI5 probabilities differ from predict_proba

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, multilabel-classification, tfidfvectorizer, eli5

I have an sklearn pipeline consisting of a `TfidfVectorizer` and a `SGDClassifier(loss='log')`, fitted on a multi-label training dataset. When I then use ELI5 `explain_prediction` on a sample (using the vectorizer and classifier from pipeline), I get different probabilities than when I use `pipeline.predict_proba` on the same sample. Why is this?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Comment: Have you set `random_state` to the same values? Can you share the relevant part of your eli5 and sklearn model initialisation?